# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix-transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> If we have the linear operator: $T\begin{pmatrix} 
> a & b \\
> c & d \\
> \end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix} 
> 2c & a+c \\
> b-2c & d \\
> \end{pmatrix}$
>   How would I find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

What I was trying to do was making the $$\det\left(\lambda I- \begin{pmatrix} 
2c & a+c \\
b-2c & d \\
\end{pmatrix}\right)$$ But somehow I feel this is wrong, how can I do it?

Comment: Are we doing your homework?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} 
2c & a+c \\
b-2c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}$ is not the matrix of $T$. Assume $T=\begin{bmatrix}p&q\\r&s\\\end{bmatrix}$ and find $p,q,r,s$ using the description of $T$ given.

Comment: Hahaha not my homework, I am introducing myself to eigenvalues

Comment: 4 questions in 3 hours. Take time to breath...

Answer (score 1):

There is no use of the matrix structure, meaning we can decide on an order as long as we stay consistent:
$$
T
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2c \\
a+c \\
b-2c \\
d
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
In turn, there is a 4 by 4 matrix that accomplishes this. Find it and its eigenvalues

This is the same idea as for polynomials of degree no larger than some $k.$ It is a matter of being careful about picking a basis (not necessarily writing it out) and writing in that basis.