# Find the associated matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose 
$$\mathrm{T}\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix} 
d & -b \\
-c & a 
\end{bmatrix},$$ can we determine the corresponding matrix of this linear transformation?   Is it 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}?
$$

Comment: With respect to which basis?

Comment: I just did one of these a minute ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157130/eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-of-a-matrix-transformation/3157144#3157144

Comment: The space of $2\times2$ matrix has dimension $4$, so the matrix of $T$ must be $4\times4$.

Comment: but how could we multiply a 4*4 matrix with a 2*2 matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your linear transformation is a map $T:M_2\to M_2$, where $M_2$ is the four dimensional vector space of $2\times 2$-matrices. A basis for this vector space is $E_{11}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, $E_{12}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, $E_{21}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, and $E_{22}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. Looking at your formula above, you should see that
$T(E_{11})=E_{22}$, $T(E_{12})=-E_{12}$, $T(E_{21})=-E_{21}$, and $T(E_{22})=E_{11}$. Therefore, the matrix for $T$ is this basis is
$$[T]=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$